# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userx'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

I have been facing a sql exception as in this title.

This error only occurs when I try to insert data to a database(MySQL) using Java(web application),
but sql operations such as update and select are executed with no errors.
(The userx does have all the privileges to the DB)

I have not had such error before making a single change to my system, which is following:

- Move locally installed database to Amazon RDS

I did not make any changes to my code, sql or whatsoever...

What could be the cause of this error?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your public ip address is allowed into RDS ACL(I suppose so). Then try to create a userx@yourpublicipaddress and grant all provileges to it. Then try your insert. This configuration is working for me in our Application. Hope this can works for you.

Comment: Actually I set it like following: 
 "userx@%"
So he can access the DB from anywhere...
The problem is the "Accessed dined" occurs upon inserting not other sql operations like update and select.

Comment: I understand you point, my suggestion was to create a user bound to an IP that is explicitly allowed in the ACL. If this still doesn't work then the problem is somewhere in GRANTS otherwise for some reason   was preventing the "user from everywhere" making inserts. This is an investigation step I generally do when I have similar problems

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error is caused by the following code for loading and inserting data from a tsv file to a table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ?
        REPLACE INTO TABLE product_p FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES...
```

The "LOCAL" should explicitly be set as ↓ for RDB(MySQL).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ?
        REPLACE INTO TABLE product_p FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES...
```